# MainMenu.ini in WinEdt 10.3 doesn't work as supposed

Tags: winedt

I have created this in MainMenu.ini in WinEdt 10.3:

```
 ITEM="TeX:Compile"
    CAPTION="&Compile"
    CONFIG_FILTER="MiKTeX;TeX Live|Default"
    IMAGE="Compile"
    SAVE_INPUT=1
    MACRO="Exe('%b\Exec\TeX\Compile.edt');"
    SHORTCUT="122::F11"
    REQ_FILTER=:"%!M=TeX"|"%!M=TeX:STY"|"%!M=TeX:AUX"
  ITEM="TeX:Compile_Selected"
```

But WInEdt 10.3 doesn't react to the hot key F11 at all.
I have saved MainMenu.ini and also load it as a script.
But NOTHING happens. Why ? There are no more occurrences of F11 in the MainMenu.ini file.

Comment: in my ini F11 is  used in the search menu/submenu bookmarks.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That's a good point. F11 after replacing your search with F12 instead of F11 now works.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Could you please have a look at [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/557925/macro-manual-for-winedt-10-3-in-pdf-where-do-i-find-it) ?