# Macro manual for WinEdt 10.3 in pdf - where do I find it?

Tags: macros, winedt, documentation

I need the Macro manual for WinEdt 10.3 in pdf - where do I find it ?

Comment: I don't think that it exists. You could print the help file to pdf.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Could you please give an answer how do I do that ? Thank you.

Comment: klick on print and then choose a pdf printer. microsoft to pdf is normally installed.